# Textarea text-Voice to Text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, voice-recognition

**html**

```html
<form>
    <label>Enter Text: </label>
    <textarea placeholder="Enter text here for detection." id="name" name="name" autofocus class="result" >
    </textarea>
</form>
<div class="options" style="display:none">
    <div class="anguage" >
        <p>Language</p>
        <select name="input-language" id="language"></select>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn record" id='myid'>
    <p><b>  Start Listening</b></p>
</button>
<div style="margin-top:-50px;" class="buttons">
    <button class="btn clear" id='clr' style="margin-left:150px" onClick="eraseText()">
        <b>Clear</b>
    </button>
</div>
```

**Btn clear function**

```js
<script>
function eraseText(){
document.getElementById('name').value='';
}
</script>
```

**Voice to Text conversion code**

```js
<script>
    const languages = [
        {
            no: "16",
            name: "English",
            native: "English",
            code: "en",
        }
    ];
    const recordBtn = document.querySelector(".record"),
    result = document.querySelector("result"),
    inputLanguage = document.querySelector("#language")
    clearBtn = document.querySelector(".clear");
  
    let SpeechRecognition =
    window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition,
    recognition,
    recording = false;

    function populateLanguages() {
        languages.forEach((lang) => {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = lang.code;
        option.innerHTML = lang.name;
        inputLanguage.appendChild(option);});
    }

    populateLanguages();
    function speechToText() {
        try {
            recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
            recognition.lang = inputLanguage.value;
            recognition.interimResults = true;
            recordBtn.classList.add("recording");
            recordBtn.querySelector("p").innerHTML = "<p style='margin-top:8px'>Stop Listening...</p>";
            recognition.start();
            recognition.onresult = (event) => {
            const speechResult = event.results[0][0].transcript;
            //detect when intrim results
            if (event.results[0].isFinal) {
                result.innerHTML = " " + speechResult;
                result.querySelector("p").remove();
            } 
            else {
                //creative p with class interim if not already there
                if (!document.querySelector(".interim")) {
                const interim = document.querySelector('textarea')
                interim.classList.add("interim");
                result.appendChild(interim);
                }
                //update the interim p with the speech result
                document.querySelector("textarea").innerHTML =" " + speechResult;
            }
            };
            recognition.onspeechend = () => {
                speechToText();
            };
            recognition.onerror = (event) => {
            stopRecording();
            if (event.error === "no-speech") {
                alert("No speech was detected. Stopping...");
            } else if (event.error === "audio-capture") {
                alert(
                "No microphone was found. Ensure that a microphone is installed."
                );
            } else if (event.error === "not-allowed") {
                alert("Permission to use microphone is blocked.");
            } else if (event.error === "aborted") {
                alert("Listening Stopped.");
            } else {
                alert("Error occurred in recognition: " + event.error);
            }
            };
        } 
        catch (error) 
        {recording = false;
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    recordBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (!recording) {
            speechToText();
            recording = true;
        } 
        else {
            stopRecording();
        }
    });


    function stopRecording() {
        recognition.stop();
        recordBtn.querySelector("p").innerHTML = "<b> Start Listening</b>";
        recordBtn.classList.remove("recording");
        recording = false;
    }
</script>
```

I am converting voice to text in a textarea. When I load a page than the start listening button works perfectly, but when I press clear button than using the start listening button, it works but the data that I speak is not written to the textbox. For checking issue, I used alert statement for printing new data that is spoken in the alert box. The new data spoken is found and printed in the alert box.

I am confused why the new spoken data is not printing in the textarea box after using clear button when listening button working perfectly. Is there any way to get rid of this problem? I mean to say to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You declare this: const result = document.querySelector("result")
So the result, is the textarea element. Later do this:

```
function speechToText() {
   ...
   if (!document.querySelector(".interim")) {
      //const interim  referd to the same element with const result
      const interim = document.querySelector('textarea')

      interim.classList.add("interim")
      //and you add it as a child to itself.....???
      result.appendChild(interim)
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: There is no difference between your provided solution and my given code

Comment: This is your own code with my own comments, so you can see that you are doing something that in my opinion you shouldn't... and after you understand what you are doing, then think about fixing it.